# Characteristic collection of rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have been trying to study ring theory to improve my algebra. One problem I have is that I have poor intuition about the general structure of rings that are not commutative. Could someone with a good understanding of ring theory give me a list of rings or families of rings that exhibit the different important structural properties? Are their archetypical examples that ring theorists think about to get intuition?

For an example of what I have in mind, if someone asked me this question about finite abelian groups, I would list direct products of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ as a characteristic family.

Comment: The simplest non-commutative division ring is the quaternions, maybe play around with them for a bit!

Comment: Dear thyde641, Characteristic classes has a different (very specific meaning) in differential topology/geometry, which is what the tag refers to, so I removed it.  I also corrected a typo in the "ring theory" tag.  Regards,

Comment: See §1 of Lam's First Course in Noncommutative rings.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that it would be hard to give a really concise answer. If you google 'classification of rings' you get quite a number of non-trivial results, I for my part have never heard of. For a start I'd say endomorphism rings (in particular matrices with entries in other rings) are quite important. Or you could look at rings $\mathbb Z_p$  (*not* $\mathbb Z/p$ !) as an example of complete rings. Then there are a number of properties that rings can have which are important depending on what you want to do. To name a few: Discrete valuation rings, Dedekind domains, principal ideal domains, local rings, henselian rings, euclidean domains...